# MDX Query to extract date & use it as a string to filter data

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a field called **forecast version** which stores version in the format as "FY20 January Forecast" and sales time field which stores date. What I want is my MDX query to filter data for the last two forecast versions based on current date. 
Eg. if current date is oct 2019, it should show me the data for **FY20 Sep forecast** and **FY20 Oct forecast**.

I want to use it similar to where condition in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example below. In my first query I am retruning "Internet Sales Amount" 
for May 2013.

```
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
}
on columns,
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2013]&[5]
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Next we modify it to return the two months before "May 2013"

```
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
}
on columns,
([Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2013]&[5]).lag(2):([Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2013]&[5]).lag(1)
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Edit : To make the query dynamic

```
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
}
on columns,
strtoset('[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&['+cstr(datepart("yyyy",Now()))+ ']&['+cstr(datepart("m",Now()))+'].lag(2):[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&['+cstr(datepart("yyyy",Now()))+ ']&['+cstr(datepart("m",Now()))+'].lag(1)')
--Output of the above expression is 
--[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2019]&[10].lag(2):[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2019]&[10].lag(1)
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Comment: But I don't want to hard code a month. I want it to be dynamic depending on current month

Comment: Made the above query dynamic. But make sure that you modify the expression according to your hierarchy

Comment: @aarti any luck with the above query?